# Creating WooCommerce placeholder for Emails sent

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

My client, a courier company, is using delivery software that is able to track with both WooCommerce order no. and ID, which means it requires both order no. and ID ("wc_order_abcdefg") to work, I believe this falls in the phpmyadmin database of post_password column.

Full tracking ID goes like: wc_order_abcdefg.66

So in the WooCommerce email settings, it only has {order_number}. How do I create one for {order_id}?

Comment: what's the difference between `WooCommerce order no.` and `ID`. which ID is it, how is it being stored ?

Comment: Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask"). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the snippet editor.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, your shipment tracking number is `{order_key}.{order_number}`.
Once you get hold of the `order` object, you can get its key simply with: `$order->get_order_key()`.

`{order_key}` is not available as an email placeholder. So in order to include it in the email sent to the customer, you have different options depending on where you want it to be displayed. For example:

- You could include the tracking number in the body of the email. In this case, you can override one of the WooCommerce email templates (e.g. `email-order-details.php`). See the [WooCommerce docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) for more info on how to override templates.
- You could include the tracking number in the subject of the email. In this case, you can use the `woocommerce_email_subject_customer_completed_order` filter. E.g. (this snippet should be added to your functions.php):

  ```
  add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_subject_customer_completed_order', 'add_tracking_number_to_email_subject', 1, 2 );
  function add_tracking_number_to_email_subject( $subject, $order ) {
    return sprintf( 'Thank you for your order! Your shipment tracking number is: %s.%s', $order->get_order_key(), $order->get_id() );
  }
  ```

Comment: Hi, thanks, your inputs have made me understand more. I have downloaded snippets plugin, what is the snippet for me to add to functions.php if I wants to include in the order processing email.

Comment: As far as I know, the snippets plugin is just a simpler way to run PHP code compared to editing the `functions.php` file directly. You have a couple of options: you can either use an existing hook (e.g. `woocommerce_email_after_order_table` which allows you to place content below the order table of an order processing email), or you override the email template (e.g. `email-order-details.php`). If you decide to use a hook, you can then use the snippets plugin to run the code on your site.